# How to get the list of dates 15 days from now in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a column in my database with date format and I have to get dates within 15 days from today .

I am using below query that does not seem to work, can someone please guide me how can i get it

```
$query= "Select * From  cases   WHERE   deadline >= DATE_ADD(DAY, 15, GETDATE())";
$result=$this->db->query($query)->result();
```

Deadline col in table has below value : **2021-05-20** and type is **date**

Below is the error i get :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '15, GETDATE())' at line 1

Comment: col name is deadline, table name is cases   and i have to get daedline date that is higher that 15 days from now

Comment: Could you please share what result you are getting now?

Comment: i get below error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '15, GETDATE())' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM cases WHERE deadline >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 15 DAY";
```

Comment: If you still facing the same error means kindly let me know.

Comment: first query gives me below error   :: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '15, GETDATE()) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1    second one :  #1305 - FUNCTION dbname.Getdate does not exist

Comment: Second query gives you?

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION dbname.Getdate does not exist –

Comment: Getdate does not exist

Comment: I have updated my query above....just try CURDATE() function instead of GETDATE() and let me know if you still facing the same error.

Comment: so this returns all the daets within next 15 days ?

Comment: Yes, did you get your final output?

Comment: Select * From cases WHERE deadline <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 15 DAY , Yes